# htaccess working in local host but no in GoDaddy

Tags: php, .htaccess, hosting

after a long search I finally created an htaccess file with the rules i need. In the local host everything works fine but on the GoDaddy hosting only the half rules are working... does anyone had the same problem or know how to solve it? Thank you

```
# THIS IS NOT WORKING / Returns a page not found error
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/?customize/?$ all_poi.php
RewriteRule ^/?santorini/?$ santorini.php
RewriteRule ^/?aboutus/?$ aboutus.php
RewriteRule ^/??tours/?$ all_tours.php
RewriteRule ^/?tours/([0-9]+) tours.php?tour_id=$1& [L]


# Redirects to https / WORKING
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?mywebsite\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.mywebsite.com/$1  [R=301,L]

#remove trailing slash / WORKING
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301] # <- for test, for prod use [L,R=301]

# Removes index.php from ExpressionEngine URLs / WORKING
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET.*index\.php [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/system/.* [NC]
RewriteRule (.*?)index\.php/*(.*) /$1$2 [R=301,NE,L]
```

Comment: Hi Thomas, Welcome to SO. Please the rules you think are not working.

Comment: RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^ustomize?$ all_poi.php
RewriteRule ^santorini?$ santorini.php
RewriteRule ^aboutus?$ aboutus.php
RewriteRule ^tours?$ all_tours.php
RewriteRule ^tours/([0-9]+) tours.php?tour_id=$1& [L]

Comment: Thank you for your super fast reply! In the comment mode is not so clear...would it be more helpful to edit my original post?

Comment: It would be better.

Comment: What is `^santorini?$` meant to express anyway? The trailing "i" is optional? Or did you mean `^/?santorini/?$`?

Comment: I have added the htaccess file .  santorini.php should be reached when the user types mywebsite.com/santorini

Comment: OK, then you certainly should fix those patterns, the current patterns work in certain situations, but they do not express what you probably want.

Comment: Next you will to tell is what "does not work" actually means. _In detail._

Comment: when the users type  www.mywebsite.com/santorini  it should go to www.mywebsite.com/santorini.php but instead it returns a page not found error

Comment: I just fixed those patterns but still returns a page not found error

Comment: I'd say it should be `RewriteRule ^/?santorini/?$ /santorini.php [END]`, but that is not the issue here... The rules _should_ work, unless there are no _other_ rules that interfere... You would need to debug the rewriting engine using rewrite logging, but that probably is not possible with the cheap hosting you use.

Comment: What happens if you access `/santorini.php` directly, does _that_ work?

Comment: yes, it works fine. but when i type /santorini  --> page not found

Comment: I am on the phone with Godaddy support now... should i ask them to do the debug for me?

Comment: I am stuck here...do not know what to do or how should i search for it..